# Is there a way to download previous versions of Bitnami WAMP stack?

Tags: download, stack, wamp, upgrade, bitnami

I have an application that works on a previous version of the WAMP stack.
There are couple of changes in Apache, which were not relevant when the application was on that stack, but now are. This also prevents the application to run on the current stack.

To get it working, I need the older version of WAMP stack. Any way I can download that? Or a suggested path to upgrade to newer versions of the WAMP stack?

Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to know what versions of wamp stack you are using and what versions you think you now need?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly...I needed version 5.4.15, and got a link from Bitnami.

Answer (score 8):

You can search for it in archive.org.
The file has the same url but it's not linked in the description page.

For example, now I need the dmg file of the version 3.0 of redmine, so I go to: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer

And copy the url from the download link from a date prior to the launch of the 3.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami developer here. You can request the version of the stack that you want in the community forum of Bitnami. You have to create a new post and tell the stack and the version that you want. https://community.bitnami.com

I hope it helps.